# Networkx: Get the distance between nodes

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

I'm a beginner at using NetworkX and I'm trying to find a way to detect which nodes have distance x from each other.
I've started by using this algorithm to get all pairs

```
path=nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path(G)
```

But I'm still unsure on how to detect the distance between nodes using a for loop.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Which distance are you talking about exactly? The minimal number of edges between two nodes?

Comment: For example I have a straight path graph consisting of 5 nodes [A,B,C,D,E] with edges (A,B) (B,C) (C,D) (D,E) and I would like to know the distance between A node and D node. Of course I will use this in a much larger program but I would like to know the approach I should use. Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

NetworkX has methods for automatically calculating the shortest paths (or just the path lengths) for weighted and unweighted graphs. Make sure that you use the correct method for your use case.

[networkx.all_pairs_shortest_path](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path) - calculates the shortest paths between all nodes in an *unweighted* graph

[networkx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path_length.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path_length) - calculates the lengths of the shortest paths between all nodes in an *unweighted* graph

[networkx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path) - calculates the shortest paths between all nodes in a *weighted* graph

[networkx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length) - calculates the lengths of the shortest paths between all nodes in a *weighted* graph

Every one of these methods, when executed on a graph, will calculate a dictionary matrix (a "dictionary of dictionaries") of nodes with either the respective shortest path or length of the shortest path as values. I'll demonstrate this with an example:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_nodes_from(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
>>> G.add_edges_from([("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("C", "D"), ("D", "E")])
>>> sp = dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G))
>>> sp["A"]["E"]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
>>> spl = dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G))
>>> spl["A"]["E"]
4
```

As you can see, I generated a graph with five nodes and linked every node to the next one with an edge. I stored a matrix of the shortest paths in `sp` and a matrix of the shortest path lengths in `spl`. When I need to know the shortest path between two nodes, e.g. node `"A"` and node `"E"`, I just access `sp` like a matrix, or a dictionary of dictionaries: `sp["A"]["E"]`. It will then return the whole shortest path between the two nodes. The method for the shortest path length works in a similar fashion, but it will return only the number of edges between any two given nodes.

The next code snippet might make it clearer what I mean with a dictionary matrix. If I request all entries in `sp` for node `"A"`, it returns another dictionary with entries for every other node:

```
>>> sp["A"]
{'B': ['A', 'B'], 'A': ['A'], 'E': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'C': ['A', 'B', 'C
'], 'D': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}
```

If you want to check out the distance between all nodes by using `for` loops, you could just iterate over the keys of the first dictionary of the matrix and then over the dictionaries inside of that dictionary. It's easier than it sounds:

```
>>> for node1 in spl:
...   for node2 in spl[node1]:
...     print("Length between", node1, "and", node2, "is", spl[node1][node2])
...
Length between B and B is 0
Length between B and A is 1
Length between B and E is 3
Length between B and C is 1
Length between B and D is 2
Length between A and B is 1
... (and so on!)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution to find distances between nodes:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4)])
path = nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G) # This is a generator
dpath = {x[0]:x[1] for x in path}           # Create a dictionary from it 
# To find e.g. the distance between node 1 and node 4: 
print(dpath[1][4]) # = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the graph you can use

```py
distances = nx.floyd_warshall_numpy(graph)
nodes = np.where(distances==4)
```

To get the distance matrix. From that you can filter for your distance. Rows and columns are nodes in `list(g)`

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this for working out longest paths - notoriously difficult with directed graphs, but easy enough for a tree-like graph.
While you aren't asking for this specifically, it may help others.
FYI, using all_pairs_shortest_path_length is extremely expensive for large networks.

```py
        # Find the longest path for a tree
        # Choose a random start. (or first).
        rnd_node = choice(nodes)
        # Find distances from random node by calculating all distances
        r_dists = dict(nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(g, rnd_node))
        begins = [node for node, dist in r_dists.items() if dist == max(r_dists.values())]
        # being the longest from a random start, makes it suitable as a start to the longest path.
        begin = choice(begins)
        # Find distances from begin by calculating all distances.
        # If we want to know the actual journey, use 'single_source_shortest_path()' instead.
        s_dists = dict(nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(g, begin))
        stops = [node for node, dist in s_dists.items() if dist == max(s_dists.values())]
        dist, stop = choice(stops)
```