# How can I make a square matrix from a nested dict?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, networkx

I am recently using networkx module, and now I am about to get distance data among countries.

So the excel raw data is something like this:

```
Nat1   Nat2   Y/N
ABW    ANT    0
ABW    ARG    0
ABW    BEK    1
ABW    BHS    1
ABW    BRA    0
...
ALB    COL    0
ALB    CYP    1
...
```

And thanks to GeckStar([Networkx: Get the distance between nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088042/networkx-get-the-distance-between-nodes)), I managed to know how the dataset is coded, as a nested dictionary.

The problem is, I am not familiar with the dictionary. If it was a nested list, I can deal with it, but the nested dict... I need help from others.

So I checked what would this give to me if I code like this:

```
distance = dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(graph))
df = pd.DataFrame(list(distance.items()))
df.to_excel("C_C.xlsx")
```

(FYI,

```
distance = dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(graph))
```

will calculate a shortest path from a nation to other nation. So if a nation is not connected to the other nation, and needs a detour, it will has a value more than 1.)

Of course, it didn't go well.

```
     0    1
0   ABW   {'ABW':0, 'ANT': 1 ..., 'BHS': 2 ...}
1   ANT   {'ANT':0, 'ABW': 1 ...}
...
3   BEL   {'BEL':0, 'ABW':1, ... 'BHS':4, ...}
...
```

But I know there should be a way to make those data to a square matrix like this:

```
    ABW   ANT   ARG    BEL    BHS ...
ABW  0     0     0      1      2 ...
ANT  0     0     1      0      1  ...
ARG  0     1     0      1      0  ...
BEL  2     0     1      0      4  ...
...
```

Can you guys enlighten me, please?
Thanks for your time to check this out, and Thank you for your solution in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a walkaround with a list.

dis = dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(graph))

```
Nations = list(dis.keys())
master = [[""]]

for x in Nations:
    master[0].append(x)

for Nat1 in dis:
    master.append([Nat1])
    for Nat2 in Nations:
        master[-1].append(dis[Nat1][Nat2])
```

Thanks for everyone taking care of this problem.
Have a wonderful day!